# Activity Indicator Continues after Block

Tags: objective-c, ios

got this code:

```
[self setQRCodeScannerMode:false];
[self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
TBXMLSuccessBlock successBlock = ^(TBXML *tbxmlDocument) {
    if ([[TBXML elementName:tbxmlDocument.rootXMLElement] isEqualToString:@"xxxxxx"]){
        [self setQRCodeScannerMode:true];
    } else {
        [self setQRCodeScannerMode:true];
    }
};
```

The thing is that when I set my scan mode to true inside the method [setQRCodeScannerMode] I'm stopping the activity indicator.
But surprise!!! the activity indicator is still working and messing with my view after some seconds.

What can I do?

Comment: after the block use `[self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];`

Comment: @I'MPOSSIBLE: it won't yield the correct output. It's stop the indicator immediately after displaying it.

Comment: Are you running the scan on a separate thread? If so, are you sure control has returned to the main run loop when stopping the activity indicator? This might explain the delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to stop the activity indicator in your completion block:

```
[self setQRCodeScannerMode:false];
[self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
TBXMLSuccessBlock successBlock = ^(TBXML *tbxmlDocument) {
    if ([[TBXML elementName:tbxmlDocument.rootXMLElement] isEqualToString:@"xxxxxx"]){
        [self setQRCodeScannerMode:true];
    } else {
        [self setQRCodeScannerMode:true];
    }

    [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
};
```

This assumes the completion block is called on the main thread. If there is no guarantee that the completion block is called on the main thread you can do this:

```
[self setQRCodeScannerMode:false];
[self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
TBXMLSuccessBlock successBlock = ^(TBXML *tbxmlDocument) {
    if ([[TBXML elementName:tbxmlDocument.rootXMLElement] isEqualToString:@"xxxxxx"]){
        [self setQRCodeScannerMode:true];
    } else {
        [self setQRCodeScannerMode:true];
    }

    if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
        [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    } else {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Good one. But just out of curiosity what is last if-else doing. I didn't get it

Comment: The call to stopAnimating (like all UI methods) must be done on the main thread. The check says if this is the main thread then stop animating, else if this is not the main thread, dispatch the call (to stop the animating) onto the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to call [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating]; after you are finished with it, if thats not working for you, try this!

```
[self.activityIndicator performSelector:@selector(stopAnimating) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
```

Hope that Helps!

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you can do is working with the indicator on a different thread i.e. not on the Main Thread. You can use NSOperationQueue and NSInvocationOperation

Comment: You cannot stop the activity indicator on a different thread. Any changes to the UI will not take place until control has returned to the main thread.

Comment: @sooper So true, but when the operation is done it should be made to communicate with the main thread

Comment: Setting up an operation is probably serious overkill just to call a single method on the main thread.

Comment: @rmaddy I would definitely like to know more. Any specific reason to this?

Comment: @EvolGate Look at the answer I posted. Much easier than setting up an operation and adding it to a queue. Operations and queue are meant for performing longer running operations in the background.

Answer (score 0):

simply add this code after the block

```
 [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
```